# When reading a csv file through pandas, all columns become a single column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, read-csv

I am unable to print a DataFrame from a CSV file. It was originally in text format, but I converted to csv through the online site. So the file looks like this: [image: picture of my csv]]

CSV code:

```
"clientId,timestamp,log"
"1,Jun 29 2023 09:36:44.933,00:07"
"36441418,Jun 29 2023 09:36:45.002,00:12 seconds"
"34836299,Jun 29 2023 09:36:44.190,00:83 seconds"
"36412881,Jun 29 2023 09:35:02.138,00:00 seconds"
"37464661,Jun 29 2023 09:36:44.705,00:18 seconds"
"1,Jun 29 2023 09:36:45.500,00:09 seconds"
"37455397,Jun 29 2023 09:36:46.221,00:15 seconds"
"38071830,Jun 29 2023 09:34:29.692,00:05 seconds"
```

python output: [image]

Comment: You will get better results if instead of sharing screenshots, you copy and paste the text of your code and part of the text of your csv. That might reveal that you file is somehow corrupted and those commas perhaps are not really commas.

Comment: It'll be the quotes around the whole line - that's not a standard CSV you probably want to convert it a different way.

Comment: `"1,Jun 29 2023 09:36:44.933,00:07"` Because you have double quotes around the _whole line_, this is interpreted as a **single** column.

Comment: @JohnGordon, thank you! It's a small file and I removed the quotes and everything worked. But how do you deal with large amounts of data?

Comment: You would deal with large amounts of data by making sure it is written properly in the first place.  Those quotes should not have been there.  Whatever process added those quotes was in error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('a.csv', "r+", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    content = csv_file.read()

with open('a.csv', "w+", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(content.replace('"', ''))

df = pd.read_csv('a.csv',delimiter=',')
print(df)
```

You have to first remove the double quotes as the others have suggested, then you can read your csv file and save it as a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Beware that while the " in your file were wrongly placed, there are other ways to use the " that are appropriate, making this delete all " inappropriate for those cases. Read more about proper double quote usage on CSV files here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 0):

The `sep=‘,’` in the `pd.read_csv()` line is redundant, removing that might help as I am not sure whether that could break it. I can try troubleshooting more if you attach/paste the csv file onto the post.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).